# Size limit with spring MVC POST form?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, post

I have a form :

```
<form:form modelAttribute="zgImport" action="${importAfterValidationUsers}" method="POST" name="ImportForm" >
```

in which I display csv content (one line per user).
My controller method get the object :

```
public void importAfterValidationUsers(@ModelAttribute ("zgImport") ZgImport zgImport, ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response) {
```

Problem is : if I have many lines (more than 670) the object "zgImport" that I get in my controller is not fully filed, I miss some data.
Is there a limit to the POST? Or with the mapping ?

Comment: Which server you are using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

POST request body size is usually limited by server and can be configured.

> The maximum size in bytes of the POST which will be handled by the
>   container FORM URL parameter parsing. The limit can be disabled by
>   setting this attribute to a value less than or equal to 0. If not
>   specified, this attribute is set to 2097152 (2 megabytes).

Source : https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/http.html

Comment: That was it! i actually get a message in the catalina.out, didn't saw that. Thx :)

Comment: Any idea if i can define it in the code or just for a specific form, to avoid changing tomcat conf?

Comment: @Lempkin Don't think it can be done through code as its server level setting.

Answer (score 2):

The size limitation on the file which Spring will be handle is being configured in the server settings.

Answer (score 2):

The body of a request (POST) is normally limited by the server on a byte size basis in order to prevent a type of DoS attack. The most common server setting is 2MB, though all popular servers allow this to be increased or decreased via a setting file or panel.
Edit Tomcat's server.xml. In the  element, add an attribute maxPostSize and set a larger value (in bytes) to increase the limit.

More info at https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/http.html